# Confused about Nulls in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I'm new to Powershell and I'm confused about something, more specifically `null` and `$null`.

For example. let's say you have a function:

```
function myFunction([ref]$foo){

if($foo -ne $null){
  ...do stuff
}
}
```

And when you call this function, you do so like:

```
[ref]$foo = $null
myFunction $foo
```

If you execute the code above, the condition `if($foo -ne $null)` will return `true`.

However, if you call the function like:

```
$foo = $null

myFunction $foo
```

the condition `if($foo -ne $null)` will return `false`.

Why is this? Why is it that when you assign a `ref` variable `$null`, it isn't considered `null` when it is checked?

Comment: @jpmc26 Um, I can't remember....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PowerShell seems to cast `$null` to some non-null value when you attempt to store it in a strongly typed variable. I believe this is the cause. Notice the following:

```
PS C:\> [ref]$foo = $null
PS C:\> $foo

Value
-----



PS C:\> $foo.GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     False    PSReference                              System.Object
```

It appears that PowerShell is casting `$null` to a `PSReference`. I've seen similar behavior with strings:

```
PS C:\> [String]$str = $null
PS C:\> $str -eq $null
False
PS C:\> $str -eq [String]::Empty
True
```

It confused the heck out of me when I had a `[String]` parameter on a function that I was defaulting to `$null` and my null check was never true.

Why would they do this? I wonder the same thing.

For strings, I ended up using `[String]::IsNullOrEmpty` (although there may be a more PowerShell-ish way). For `PSReference`, [`Value`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.psreference.value%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) might suit your needs for the null check:

```
PS C:\> [ref]$foo = $null
PS C:\> $foo.Value -eq $null
True
```

Note that we have just proven you won't run into a null reference error by accessing `Value`.

Answer (score 1):

Because $null is a special variable which is actually null, where as [ref]$foo is a strongly typed variable containing a reference to a location, which just so happens to be null.

So of course $ref -ne $null.  $null is the null, $ref is a reference which could be null later.